# How to make specific curl request in swift using URLSession

Tags: ios, swift, api, curl, request

How it looks: `curl https://token-vault.repeatphotos.xyz/token -H "Authorization: e11f18b4-5015-45ad-8276-18269a7bf047""` Response is string value. So the main question is, how to make a request and get value from this in swift?
I've tried something like this:

```
func changeApiKey() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://token-vault.repeatphotos.xyz/token")

        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("e11f18b4-5015-45ad-8276-18269a7bf047", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                print("Data is empty")
                return
            }

            let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            print(json)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: The curl command return empty response body in postman

Comment: I've edited the question with correct curl

Comment: Then print the string, it should work now. `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!`

Comment: I've tried and don't get printed the data, seems some problem in the code

Comment: Does this run on Postman?

Comment: I've tried this here https://reqbin.com/curl and it's response a string

Comment: You need to use [`dataTask(with:request)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1410592-datatask) otherwise your authorisation header won't be sent.

Comment: I've tried with request, but still got nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this, works for me, it gives "newty-token"

```
func changeApiKey() {
    if let url = URL(string: "https://token-vault.repeatphotos.xyz/token") {
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("text/plain",forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue("e11f18b4-5015-45ad-8276-18269a7bf047", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                print("Data is empty")
                return
            }
            
            let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("result: \(result)")
            
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```